# multi query and results join

Tags: php, mysql

```
require_once("./Connections/root.php");
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM performer WHERE username = '$user'");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT poster_id, wall_msg FROM performer_info WHERE id = '$r[id]'");
$r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1);
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM performer WHERE id = '$r1[poster_id]'");
$r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2);

echo $r2['username'] . " : " . $r1['wall_msg'];
```

Is it possible to use all of these queries in single query and result ?

I think, I need to use inner join but I have no idea about it how do do it

$_SESSION['MM_Username'] is the loged in user ,username

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_8 functions

Comment: You can use join queries if three tables are mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like

```
select wall_msg from performer_info where poster_id = (select id from performer where username = '$user')
```

User name you already know...and wall_msg can be obtained from this query's result.

EDIT:

```
 select p.username, t.wall_msg from performer p, (select poster_id, wall_msg from performer_info where id=(select id from performer where username= '$user'))t where p.id = t.posterid;
```

This will only work if the inner queries return a single result. Hope it helps.

Comment: but they dont...1 returnes the poster username (from the performer table) and the other returnes the wall_msg(from the performer_info table)

Comment: but isnt poster username and MM_UserName same...In your query above you first get id from username and then get username from id, they have to be the same right ? If yes then all you need is wall_msg value which can be obtained from the query in my answer.

Comment: MM_Username is the username of the loged in user....

Comment: check my edit...that should get you all the results you want in one query

Answer (score 0):

how about an inner join ?

```
SELECT t.username , pi.wall_msg 

FROM performer t

INNER JOIN performer_info pi ON pi.id = t.id

WHERE t.username LIKE '%$user%'
```